# Pass two-channel image to conv2d

Tags: python, keras

I use Keras to Build my architecture. I have Two Inputs:

- Grayscale Image [256,256,1]
- Grayscale Image [256,255,1]

I contact this Two Images to [256,255,2]

So now I would like to pass this Two-Channel Image to the conv2D Layer. But if I plot the kernel conv2D layer use only one image of the two(only one channel of 2) 
What I do wrong?

Comment: What is the code that you are using for the first layer, what's the `input_shape` parameter?

Comment: `input1      = Input((256,256,1))
input2      = Input((256,256,1))
inputs      = concatenate([input1,input2])
conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)`

Comment: IFor first layer, use: `Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',input_shape=(256,255,2))`

Comment: Ok, I would test it.

Comment: See [Keras Conv2D](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/)

Comment: I add this line, because if i plot the kernel from first conv layer I see only the first input image